# Show this form from within new form instance

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created two forms in C# using "Add new item". Form1 is my default opening form. I'm using the following code to switch to form2:

```
Form1 class:
    Form form2= new form2();
                this.Hide();
                form2.Show();  



Form2 class:
```

what should i do here to open the same form1 again without creating the new instant of form1?

Comment: where do you want to call the form1 instance? In form1 itself after closing form2 or in form2 instance?

Comment: I have posted the solution.hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution could be showing the second form modally, then making the first form visible when the second form closes, like this:

```
  public partial class Form1: Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Form2 form2 = new Form2();
      this.Hide();
      form2.ShowDialog();
      this.Show();
    }
  }

  public partial class Form2: Form
  {
    public Form2()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Close();
    }
  }
```

Making this work non-modally is left as an exercise :)

Comment: This is not a homework. I'm working on professional application

Comment: No problem, we used to have similar tasks at the university, that's the only reason I asked.

Comment: OK, you might want to update the question then with this extra info. Do you want to do it like I did above, or just bring the 2nd form to the front?

Comment: yes i'm really sorry. I just want to know that when i close form2 form1 should open again. How should I modify your code for that?

Comment: @fawad, that's exactly what my code does. Have you tried it? Put a single button on Form1 and on Form2, hook up the event handlers and press the buttons (or simply close the 2nd form) to get the desired effect.

Comment: I did that but form1 is not showing when i close form2 using formclosing event.

Comment: No need for the FormClosing event. Just add the buttons, one to each form, and their event handlers as above. No matter how you close the second form the first one will come to the front again.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass an instance of this to form2 and have it `.Show()` it when the time comes.

Comment: how should i pass the instance of form1 to form2?

Comment: Create a property on Form2 that is of type Form1.  After instantiating it, set the property.  You may also choose to create a second constructor that takes a Form1 as a parameter and sets the property.  Don't abandon the parameterless constructor though or the designer won't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing **form2.hide()** you are actually **hiding** not **destroying** it
so the instance you have created still exist so you can use to show it again

if you use **form2.dispose()** then you have to create a new instance

Answer (score 1):

In the form2 code behind, add parameter in constructor

```
Form2(Form form1)
{
   //use form1 object here
   //you can declare a variable of Form1 in Form2 and use it everywhere in the scope of form2
}
```

Then while initialising object of form2:

```
Form form2 = new Form(this);
this.Hide();
form2.show();
```

Comment: 'form.form2' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: thats what I have mentioned in first code

add a parameter to form2 constructor

`public Form2(Form form1)`

Comment: where to add that parameter. I'm really sorry for that.